# Can a constraint be added to a database if there's data in it that violates it?

Tags: database

I'm setting up a database migration test project for work and among the issues that we want to cover, we have an old issue where some DB constraint was added, and it was overlooked that sometimes existing data is in a legacy shape that violates the constraint.

Is this a thing that can happen with modern databases? or should this be covered by some kind of tests, and if so any guidance with the tests for it? (I feel a little out of my field with this)

Comment: MS SQL Server will return an error if there is existing data that will violate the new constraint. IMO you would be better off testing prior to attempting to introduce the constraint, so you know what data has problems and can potentially make changes that are needed.

Comment: Might be better asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com/